# Filtering geolocation noise when receiving coordinated from device

Tags: android, location, coordinates, distance

people.

Had this issue the other day in an application, that would update server on location change.
Sadly, at least on Android, location update was sometimes very noisy, the different between old and new location being less than the accuracy margin.

So, for anyone that wants to filter these updates, the smple solution is provided.

Answer (score 0):

Rough calculations:

Distance between two integer latitude angles is roughly 110km

Distance between two integer longitude angles varies with latitude, and is about 110km*cos(lat).

..using Android's 68% probability accuracy in meters:

```
noise_margin=accuracy/110000;

 if (new_lat-old_lat < noise_margin ||  new_lon-old_lon < (cos(new_lat)*noise_margin))
   ignore update;
 else
   proceed with update..
```

This can probably be additionally tweaked taking into account the 68%, but it works fine as is.

P.S. This probably doesn't fit SO formatting very well, so if someone can help with that, would appreciate!